# Why does SQL Server populate new fields in existing rows in some environments and not others?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using MS SQL Server 2012. I have this bit of SQL:

```
alter table SomeTable 
        add Active bit not null default 1
```

In some environments the default value is applied to existing rows and in other environments we have to add an update script to set the new field to 1. Naturally I am thinking that the difference is a SQL Server setting but my searches thus far are not suggesting which one. Any suggestions?

Let me know if the values of particular settings are desired.

Edit: In the environments that don't apply the default the existing rows are set to 0, which at least conforms to the NOT NULL.

Comment: To add to the answers below, you also can add `with values` to your `alter` to force existing rows to update to the default (if its nullable) and skip the 2nd statement.

Comment: If you add a `not null` column to a table it won't just create it with null values. That can't be the code you are running.

Comment: It won't just make up a default of 0 either. This must be something else going on with your deployment process outside of SQL Server.

Comment: In the environments that did not appear to apply the default to the existing rows, but instead had a value of `0`: in what manner were you observing the value of `0`? Was it through an application where intermediary code could be returning the value of `0` instead of `null`?

Comment: @SqlZim No I am seeing it in Management Studio.

Comment: @MartinSmith OK I will look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the column as `not null` it will be set to the default value for existing rows.

If you add the column as `null` it will be `null` despite having a default constraint when added to the table.

---

For example:

```
create table SomeTable (id int);
insert into SomeTable values (1);

alter table SomeTable add Active_NotNull bit not null default 1;
alter table SomeTable add Active_Null bit null default 1;

select * from SomeTable;
```

returns:

```
+----+----------------+-------------+
| id | Active_NotNull | Active_Null |
+----+----------------+-------------+
|  1 |              1 | NULL        |
+----+----------------+-------------+
```

dbfiddle.uk demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c4aeea808684de48097ff44d391c9954

Comment: That was my understanding as well. But we have several machines that seem to not be behaving that way. Is that possible?

Comment: I seem to recall running into the scenario @MatthewNichols is talking about, where existing rows violate the `not null` constraint when adding a new column with a default value.

Comment: I omitted to say that the environments that did not apply default to existing rows were set to 0. On one hand this makes sense since it is not a nullable column. I will update question

Answer (score 0):

Default value will be applied to existing row to avoid violation of "NOT NULL" constraint.